# function in .html(function(x)) does not return html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array containing 10 objects. Each contains a question string, a `correctAnswer` string, and an object with 4 answer strings:

```
const DB = [
{
  question: "some question",
  answers: ["a", "variety", "of", "choices"],
  correctAnswer: "variety"
}, ...
```

I have a function which captures the user's answer via radio button input, and saves it in a variable:

```
function getFeedback(){
  return $("form input[type=radio]:checked")
           .closest('.css-answerscss-answers')
           .children('label')
           .text()
}

function feedbackPage(){
  $('.js-quizform-questions').on('click', '.js-button-next', function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let yourAnswer = getFeedback()
    $('.js-feedback-page').show().html(evalCorrectAnswer(DB))
  })
}
```

The last line then calls `evalCorrectAnswer()` with a parameter of DB. I want to compare the answer given by the user (`yourAnswer`) to the `correctAnswer` in DB. All the console logs work in that they return the correct and same answers. Yet the `Correct`/`Wrong` html is not sent back:

```
function evalCorrectAnswer(yourAnswer){
  console.log(yourAnswer)
  console.log(DB[0].correctAnswer)
  if (DB[0].correctAnswer === yourAnswer){
    `<p>Correct</p>`
  } else {
    `<p>Too bad</p>`
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: you need to return those strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement, make it

```
function evalCorrectAnswer(yourAnswer){
  console.log(yourAnswer)
  console.log(DB[0].correctAnswer)
  return DB[0].correctAnswer === yourAnswer ? `<p>Correct</p>` : `<p>Too bad</p>`;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe i missed this. I had the `DB[0].correctAnswer === yourAnswer ? `<p>Correct</p>` : `<p>Too bad</p>` this exact same way, but never `return`ed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

isn't a `return` call missing? Inside the `if/else`

like this:

```
if (DB[0].correctAnswer === yourAnswer){
    return `<p>Correct</p>`; 
} else {
    return `<p>Too bad</p>`;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the value! Like in

```
...
return '<p>Correct</p>';
...
```

Also make sure that you use the correct quotation marks,`'` instead of ```.

Answer (score 0):

Some languages allow you to return a value with just a single statement (return becomes implicit). JavaScript is not one of those languages. To return the result of the function you need to explicitly use a `return` statement.

Minimal fix to your code:

```
 function evalCorrectAnswer(yourAnswer){
   console.log(yourAnswer)
   console.log(DB[0].correctAnswer)
 if (DB[0].correctAnswer === yourAnswer){
   return '<p>Correct</p>'
 } else {
   return '<p>Too bad</p>'
 }
}
```